# Community Promotion Ads - 2017

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It is a bit late into this new year, being that we're already in the second month, but we are now cycling the Community Promotion Ads for 2017!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- useful resources for both the GM and the player
- utilities for running meets online
- the site's twitter account
- cool roleplaying events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/6717).

Answer (score 16):

[image: Great RPGs have great worlds!]

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to propose an edit, but please consider [this ad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrIsG.png) instead.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Why not both? :) (Or is it that the WB community is retiring this one?)

Comment: Well, if you guys *want* two WB ads I don't *mind*, but we think the new ad is better than this one.

Comment: @Monica No problem! I've updated this ad.

Comment: When I made this ad (the one currently used in this answer), I intended it for SFF.SE. If you guys think it's sufficient, then I won't argue, but I'd kinda rather make a new one for RPG.SE if you want one.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh RPGs cover the same kinds of genres, so I think it works, but if you want to suggest a different design to your fellow WBers, that's cool! Whatever WB ends up designing for RPG, let us know.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Sounds good, I'll sketch something up and see what the WB community thinks of it

Comment: @SevenSidedDie tbh this *is* pretty representative of occasional RPG gameplay. :)

Comment: I did finally draw the ad I intended to post here, [see here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4787/6507) the image posted on WB Meta. I think it's been pretty well accepted by the community there, but I leave it to you (and/or the RPG community) to decide whether RPG wants to use it.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh I am gobsmacked, that ad is fantastic. (I kind of even want to have both.) Nice work. I've edited it in.

Answer (score 15):

[image: Roll20 Virtual Tabletops]

Comment: Brought forward from [last year](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/6024).

Answer (score 12):

[image: RPG.SE Twitter]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting

Answer (score 12):

[image: Community Promotion Ads - 2017]

Comment: Brought forward from [last year](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/6024). Based on the [ad designed by dpatchery in 2012](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/1565/321).

Answer (score 12):

[image: MapTool Virtual Tabletop]

Comment: Brought forward from [last year](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/6024). Credits from last year: *“I’ve noticed comments with credits, which are appropriate. So, credit where credit is due: the elements of this ad are all by RPTools, the gear being the icon on their website for MapTool, and the compass, “MapTool”, and “By RPTools” logos are from the splash screen when starting up MapTool itself. I rearranged these to fit as an ad. – KRyan [Feb 2 '16 at 16:42](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6024/community-promotion-ads-2016/6518#comment17436_6031)”*

Answer (score 12):

[image: See all questions with active bounties]
<sub>(source: [herokuapp.com](https://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/rpg.stackexchange.com/bounty.png))</sub>

Comment: Copied from other metas; it's dynamic and will change iff there are questions with bounties. The size is *not* a problem.

Comment: Cool, thanks for adding this! The post code from last year wasn't working, so thanks for finding a version that does.

Comment: Re: recent changes to SE, modified this to point to https:// explicitly - it is now required for all images

Answer (score 12):

[image: Mipui - a free collaborative map editor]

Comment: Mipui is an online map editor I've been developing, which supports real-time collaboration between different editors. Plus it's just plain convenient :-) it's free and open-source at https://github.com/amishne/mipui

Comment: 2Oak--I've got to say, I feel like there are screenshots that would do a better job of showcasing your editor. With the image that's given it'd be forgivable for someone to assume you've made a "draws polygons and places text on graph paper" tool, which I feel undersells the thing.

Comment: @nitsua60 that image worked well so far, probably because it's a familiar map for many. But I would be delighted if you could show be a better example!

Answer (score 11):

[image: Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange]

Comment: Credit: [CreationEdge](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/10595/23570). Mouse-over text: _Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange_.

Answer (score 10):

[image: Literature StackExchange]

Comment: [This is a repost of this ad.](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/6518/30848)

Comment: Ad designed by BESW.

Answer (score 8):

[image: Help support the Cartography SE in Area 51]

Comment: Brought forward from [last year](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/6024).

Answer (score 8):

[image: Board & Card Games Stackexchange]

Answer (score 6):

[image: Put some points in crafting!]

Comment: Brought forward from [last year](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/6024).

Answer (score 5):

[image: EN World RPG News & Reviews]

Comment: Brought forward from [last year](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/6024).

Answer (score 2):

[image: writers.se weekly chat event]

Comment: Brought forward from [last year](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/6024).