# 2018 200-word RPGs: user testimonials

Tags: discussion, just-for-fun

## The [2018 200-word RPG contest](https://200wordrpg.github.io/) results have arrived.

You can [see the finalists here](https://200wordrpg.github.io/winners) or [all 2018 entries](https://200wordrpg.github.io/2018entries).

If you're not aware, the 200-word RPG contest is a free, public competition in which numerous stackizens have participated over the years.

Here we collect stackizen reflections/reviews/impressions of entries from the 2018 contest.

Let's have each "answer" be one game+one person. So if you've got multiple games you want to talk about, go ahead and post multiple "answers." If you want to write about a game that's already been written about either speak up in an existing answer's comments or post anew if you've got more to say.

---

Disclaimer: I am a reader for the contest.

Comment: Did we lose [community promotion ads](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6717/8610)? The event seems a natural fit.

Comment: That's a good point! I'll try to remember to whip one up next year when it comes around (late spring).

Answer (score 2):

## [Sidewalkia!](https://200wordrpg.github.io/2018/rpg/winner/2018/05/18/Sidewalkia.html)

Read it and immediately wanted to go out and give it a try. (Probably doesn't hurt that I work on a school campus and could group-text my RPG club to witness the start--they jumped right in.) A good, quick, game for a group/setting when acting bizarre in full public view isn't a bad thing.

The rule about expanding doesn't quite parse--we just expanded when people were jostling for space.

Comment: I suspect the expansion is if you have more than 4 people in a square, you can expand and redistribute, if I had to guess.

Comment: I can't actually see a way in the Sidewalkia rules to expand beyond a 2nd square. (Or what happens if you started with 4 players.)

Comment: @doppelgreener Pose these questions on Main?

Comment: @doppelgreener I'll second the suggestion of posting mainsite--if only for the (underhanded?) reason that it and the resulting 200-word tag it'd likely create would create a little more visibility for the project =)

Comment: @HeyICanChan Asked as suggested: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/130402/1204

Comment: @nitsua60 fyi ^

Answer (score 1):

## [Letters to the Home Front](https://200wordrpg.github.io/2018/rpg/finalist/2018/05/21/LetterstotheHomeFront.html)

Teared up just reading through this one. I haven't found the person in my life to sit and try this with, but I won't consider it complete until I do.

[note: replacing the word "moral" with "morale" is the reading I gave it]

Answer (score 0):

## [Escape Pod One](https://200wordrpg.github.io/2015/rpg/winner/2015/04/01/EscapePodOne.html)

Fast paced, easy, betraying your friends, **actual gameplay mechanics**!

What's not to love about this game?

Takes hardly any prepwork.  You need a 30 second stopwatch (like your phone), and a bunch of coins (like those pennies in your couch).

This game seems like it'd be so freakin' tense, waiting for someone else to make the first move.  The winning strategy is to wait until the last second to go all in, but if you wait too long you die!

I can't wait to round up a bunch of friends to try this one out.  Most of the listed RPGs are just creative (and sometimes awkward) ways to write stories, but this one is likely the best example of the ***G*** in **RPG**.