# Community Promotion Ads — 2019

Tags: discussion, community-ads

2019 is here! And with the new year, as usual, comes a new iteration of **Community Promotion Ads**! Let’s refresh these for the coming year :)

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- useful resources for both the GM and the player
- utilities for running meets online
- the site's twitter account
- cool roleplaying events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/8737).

Answer (score 23):

[image: Writing.SE]

Comment: Thanks to linksassin for [suggesting](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1766/1993) this ad.

Comment: I like the look of the ad! Seems... spooky.

Comment: This is the best ad EVER.

Comment: @JPChapleau - Ha! Thanks for the compliment.

Answer (score 19):

[image: Great RPGs have great worlds!]

Comment: "How do we kill it?" - rpg.se

Comment: Y'know, downvoters, I'd rather this ad popped up every third time than see the site cycle through only the Twitter and bounty ad. Just sayin'. `:-)`

Comment: @goodguy5 Worldbuilding would welcome an ad from RPG.  You've advertised on our site in the past.

Answer (score 12):

[image: See all questions with active bounties]

Comment: How about the [200-word RPG contest](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8252/8610)? (No affiliation on my part; it was just something that came up in the last year that I thought was cool.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan I'd be happy to have a community ad for it, only we don't have an image for that ad.

Comment: Darn it. The [200-word RPG site](https://200wordrpg.github.io/judges) has links to the organizers' own pages—one link goes to an insecure connection (*Aw!*) and the other's page doesn't seem to have contact information. Maybe someone else will have better luck.

Comment: @glorfindel FYI the link correction script should maybe not try to rescue the `stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/*` URLs

Comment: @doppelgreener you're right, thanks for the ping - I built an exception for those links a couple of years ago, but apparently it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: The last time that script ran, HTTPS links to dynamic ads still worked (and the script just had to do a `http://` --> `https://` replacement). This will be fixed in a new version.

Answer (score 12):

[image: Mipui - a free collaborative map editor]

Comment: Brought over from [last year](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7721/community-promotion-ads-2018/7726#7726).

Comment: @Oak I like the new image. :)

Comment: @V2Blast trying to show off different themes! :-)

Comment: @Oak This looks great! FYI though this needs a 1px border: "If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it."

Comment: @doppelgreener Forgot about it :-) fixed!

Comment: @Oak Perfect! Thanks for that.

Answer (score 9):

[image: Roll20 Virtual Tabletops]

Comment: Brought over from [last year](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7725/30299).

Answer (score 8):

[image: MapTool Virtual Tabletop]

Comment: Brought over from [last year](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7721/community-promotion-ads-2018/7734#7734).

Answer (score 6):

[image: RPG.SE Twitter]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting

Answer (score 1):

[image: Worldbuilding.SE Swag]

Comment: If [rpg.se] has swag, we'd be delighted to return the favor!